# How to hover areas with XY coordinates shift in MapboxGL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I use hover tooltips in my map. When an area is hovered, I show a tooltip with a small XY shift to the top left corner so that the pointer of the tooltip is not covered by the mouse cursor.

[image: Hover effect]

When I move mouse cursor to another area, near its border, like show in the image, the area is highlighted which is under the cursor, not under the square pointer as should be.

What are options to fix this issue? In the ideal way, I would like hover effect to be applied not to the mouse cursor coordinates, but to the coordinates of some other point that is known and changes while mouse is moving.

Comment: Can you post a jsbin or jsfiddle of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem that I tried to solve with a different approach. I wanted to calculate the centroid of the polygon and always place the marker (in your case square pointer) on the calculated position once the user hovers over the polygon.

Main problem I had was that my polygons were concave and had holes in them (you will have the same problem if you are working with country borders) so I found a good algorithm (library) that I used to do this called [Polylabel](https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel).

[image]

You can read more on this topic and how the guys from MapBox used it to solve their label positioning problems on this [link](https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc).

Although this is not the answer to your question I found that this solution is fast and usable but only if the relation between the zoom level and polygon surface makes sense.

If I wanted to do something like you are suggesting I would first have a default point offset and if that offset goes outside the polygon I would find the nearest point in the polygon coordinates and attach it to that point.

To do these calculations you can use [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) library. It has the [function](http://turfjs.org/docs#booleanContains) to return boolean value if the second geometry is completely contained by the first geometry and others that can help you to find the nearest point on the polygon border. I hope this helps!